# ARM inline assembler - Strange behaviour for array input

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

i have some strange behaviour on this ARM inline assembler.
I am working on hisilicon 3531 board. I am compiling my code with these options:

-march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm

This is the code:

```
#define N   134217728

d = (float*)memalign(16, N);
x = (float*)memalign(16, N);
for(i = 0; i < N/4; i++) x[i] = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
float coeff[8] = {1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6};

for(i=0; i<N/4; i++) 
{
    asm volatile ("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[0]) : "s0");
    asm volatile("flds s1, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (x[i]) : "s1", "memory");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[1]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[2]) : "s0");
    asm volatile("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[3]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[4]) : "s0");
    asm volatile ("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[5]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[6]) : "s0");
    asm volatile("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile ("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[7]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile ("fsts s2, %[mem]\n\t" : [mem]"=m" (d[i]) : : "s2");
}
```

Problem is that i recieve a segmentation fault on the two lines where i pass x[i] and d[i] references.
Instead if i dont pass to the inline assembler the array references but i copy the values to temp vars (b and c), the code is working fine and results are correct:

```
for(i=0; i<N/4; i++) 
{
    asm volatile ("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[0]) : "s0");
    float b = x[i];
    asm volatile("flds s1, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (b) : "s1", "memory");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[1]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[2]) : "s0");
    asm volatile("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[3]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[4]) : "s0");
    asm volatile ("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[5]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    asm volatile("flds s0, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[6]) : "s0");
    asm volatile("fmacs s0, s2, s1\n\t" : : : "s0");
    asm volatile ("flds s2, %[mem]\n\t" : : [mem]"m" (coeff[7]) : "s2");
    asm volatile("fmacs s2, s0, s1\n\t" : : : "s2");
    float c;
    asm volatile ("fsts s2, %[mem]\n\t" : [mem]"=m" (c) : : "s2");
    d[i] = c;
}
```

What is going on here? The syntax is ok, i  double checked it on books and on various sites.
Can you help me?
Thank you!

=== EDIT 1 ===
I tried, as suggested, to put all the assembly code in a single statement but the behaviour is exactly the same. I still have to copy array values to temp values to get correct values.
Here is godbolt link to get code: https://goo.gl/51a3QO

Riccardo

Comment: Don't add unrelasted tags. And use a single `asm` construct for related code. There is no guarantee there will be no C code mixed in.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, i followed your suggestion and i have put all the assembly in only one asm construct. Unfortunately it has the same behavior as before :(

Comment: I did not say this solves your problem. It still is the correct way; just leave it at that. (and as you got no answer so far, please edit your question accordingly).

Comment: What is `coeff`?  Can you give a complete example?  Show the output at [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: As @Olaf suggested, do this as a single statement. Something like: `asm ("flds s0, %[m0]\nflds s1, %[mx]\nflds s2, %[m1]\nfmacs s2, s0, s1\nflds s0, %[m2]\nfmacs s0, s2, s1\nflds s2, %[m3]\nfmacs s2, s0, s1\nflds s0, %[m4]\nfmacs s0, s2, s1\nflds s2, %[m5]\nfmacs s2, s0, s1\nflds s0, %[m6]\nfmacs s0, s2, s1\nflds s2, %[m7]\nfmacs s2, s0, s1\nfsts s2, %[md]" : [md]"=m" (d[i]) : [mx]"m" (x[i]), [m0]"m" (coeff[0]), [m1]"m" (coeff[1]), [m2]"m" (coeff[2]), [m3]"m" (coeff[3]), [m4]"m" (coeff[4]), [m5]"m" (coeff[5]), [m6]"m" (coeff[6]), [m7]"m" (coeff[7]) :"s0", "s1", "s2");`. Simplified to fit here.

Comment: Since comments can only be so long, I had to trim that a bit to fit.  And I don't speak ARM, so I'm reluctant to post that an 'Answer.' You'll probably want to break that back into multiple lines (`"flds s0, %[m0]\n\t"` `"flds s1, %[mx]\n\t"` etc) and get rid of `b` and `c`.  Also, consider compiling with -S to see the actual generated output.

Comment: I have to ask; why hand-write assembly that looks like an attempt to keep the pipeline stalled on register dependencies as much as possible, rather than just writing two lines of C code and throwing -O3 (and possibly -ffast-math if applicable) at it? This looks like the kind of routine that's trivial for a compiler to optimise.

Comment: @Notlikethat maybe so.  But it's hard to compare performance if you can't get one of them to run.

Comment: @Notlikethat: i am just trying to do some exercise in assembly. I will later use assembly to speedup more complicated Computer Vision algorithms. I am just trying to do the examples i found in books and check why they are not working as supposed. (That example is from an Arm programming book).

Comment: @David Wohlferd: I tried, as suggested, to put all the assembly code in a single statement but the behaviour is exactly the same. I still have to copy array values to temp values to get the assembly work correctly.

Comment: @artless noise Here is the godbolt link: https://goo.gl/51a3QO

Comment: Since I can't run the code (no ARM dev env), I've been examining the asm output for using b+c or not, and I'm not seeing the problem.  Now that you are using a single asm, how are you using b+c?  Are you still getting seg faults or just different answers?  Can you produce the problem with a single, non-rand value for x?  Are you actually using 4.5.3 (that's what you've set in godbolt)?

Comment: The code copy-pasted from the GCC explorer example seems to work fine for me... I also translated the algorithm back to 7 lines of very readable C for a comparison (with N=100000000) - GCC 5.1 on -O2 gave much the same performance as the asm version, and -O3 came out 10-15% faster. Don't take my question the wrong way - it's perfectly valid to play with this sort of inline asm for the sake of _learning_ assembly-related stuff, just don't expect it to necessarily be worth the effort for any other reason ;)

Comment: Note: your question constant of 134217728 == 0x80000000, which is not a positive `int` value.  The godbolt and others have a smaller constant.